# Project Euler #1: Multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: java

I just tried to solve the Problem 1 of the Project Euler but I am getting java.util.NoSuchElementException.What is wrong with this code?Can any one please help?

> problem:If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples >of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below .
>
> Input Format
>
> First line contains T that denotes the number of test cases. This is >followed by  T lines, each containing an integer N, .
> Output Format
>
> For each test case, print an integer that denotes the sum of all the >multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();
        int n[]=new int[t];
        int sum[]=new int[t];
        for(int i=0;i<t;t++)
        {
            n[i]=in.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<t;t++)
        {
           sum[i]=0;
           for(int j=2;j<n[i];j++)
           if(j%3==0||j%5==0)
           sum[i]+=j;
           System.out.println(sum[i]);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please first properly indent your code, such that we can understand what you've done. This project Euler can be solved without using any `for` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of your for loops you are increasing t not i.

```
for(int i=0;i<t;t++)
```

Should be

```
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.math.*;
    import java.util.regex.*;
    public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    int sum=0;
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        int n = in.nextInt();
       sum=0;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
           if(i%3==0 || i%5==0 ||i%3==0 && i%5==0 )
           {
              sum=sum+i; 
           }   
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
                   }
        }
       }
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

t = int(input().strip())

for a0 in range(t):

```
n = int(input().strip())

total=0

for i in range(n):

    if (i%3==0):

        total=total+i

    elif (i%5==0):

        total=total+i

print(total)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).